# Xcode does not automatically indent on colon for a method name split across lines

Tags: objective-c, xcode, code-formatting, auto-indent

I'm expecting Xcode to auto-indent my method when I type a colon, but it does not. I have Automatic indent for: ":" turned on. How can I get this to work?

Example:

- type `- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name`
- press return
- type `value:(int)aValue`
- press return
- type `number:(int)aNumber;`
- press return

This is what I get

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name
value:(int)aValue
            number:(int)aNumber;
```

Why didn't it indent the second line??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the "why" is really answerable; it's annoying to be sure that <kbd>Return</kbd> doesn't seem to trigger auto-indent sometimes.

There's a workaround, though: before moving to the next line, you can type a semicolon. That triggers the indentation, and you can then delete it and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>.

It'll also indent properly if you type the method name out on one line first and then go back and insert the line breaks.

Neither of these are particularly wonderful options, of course.

Comment: Does Apple not split methods across multiple lines? This seems like basic functionality.

Comment: Usually one tab will adjust it, if your code is still 'to the left' of the desired position.

Comment: @ran: That requires the cursor to be at the start of the line.

Comment: @josh: Right, meaning you have to go back to each line and press tab.

Comment: @ran: Oh, I know what it is -- we have different Preferences. There's a setting "Tab key: Indents Always" (yours) or "Indents in leading whitespace" (mine).